ADFS SAML No AssertionConsumerService is configured on the relying party
Encountering an MSIS3110 error when attempting to log in with a trust established at https://sts.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx.
It seems that the AssertionConsumerUrl, AssertionConsumerIndex, and ProtocolBinding values are passed as empty. What additional settings are necessary for this scenario?
Any guidance would be appreciated. Thank you.
Additional Information:
The configuration details and error specifics are as follows:

Relying Party Trust Endpoints



Error:



Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
Saml 

Relying Party: 
https://sts.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/ 

Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.Policy.PolicyServer.Engine.AssertionConsumerServiceNotFoundPolicyException: MSIS3110: Cannot find AssertionConsumerService configured on the relying party trust 'https://sts.mydomain.com/adfs/ls/' that matches the request parameters: AssertionConsumerServiceIndex=, AssertionConsumerServiceUrl='', ProtocolBinding=''.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolManager.Issue(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequestMessage, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String sessionState, String relayState, String& newSamlSession, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider, Boolean isUrlTranslationNeeded, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, Boolean isKmsiRequested)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.RequestBearerToken(WrappedHttpListenerContext context, HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, SecurityTokenElement onBehalfOf, String relyingPartyIdentifier, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired, String& samlpSessionState, String& samlpAuthenticationProvider)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSerializedToken(HttpSamlRequestMessage httpSamlRequest, WrappedHttpListenerContext context, String relyingPartyIdentifier, SecurityTokenElement signOnTokenElement, Boolean isKmsiRequested, Boolean isApplicationProxyTokenRequired)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.BuildSignInResponseCoreWithSecurityToken(SamlSignInContext context, SecurityToken securityToken, SecurityToken deviceSecurityToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.Process(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)



